# I Can Connect to my SQL Server Instance through SQL Server Management and through SQL Profiler, but my VS App Will Not Connect

Tags: sql-server, database-connection

Lucky me, I got to work from home due to the COVID-19 outbreak. However, now when I try to use Visual Studio 2019 to run my app, NHibernate always fails from not finding my SQL Server instance.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I then tried to connect to my test database through SQL Server Management Studio and it worked. I have no clue why one worked and the other didn't. I don't even know where to trouble shoot this issue, I know programming, but very little about setting up a server and networking. My guess is that it's something with me no longer being on our domain anymore, but why would this affect my local instance?

I tried letting SQL Server through the firewall, I checked to make sure remote connections are allowed. I also tried connecting with my local IP instead of with localhost, using just `localhost`, or even just `(local)` and none of that worked.  I'm just completely lost otherwise.

**Edit:**

My connection string:

```
Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog={0};Integrated Security=True;
```

How I connect via SQL Server Management Studio:

[image]

Comment: Well, can you show us **how** you connect to SQL Server with Mgmt Studio, and what your connection string in your VS app looks like?

Comment: My bad, I'm kind of panicking here.  I wasn't able to get anything done all day.

Comment: It's probably looking in ODBC Data Sources for a data source named `localhost\SQLEXPRESS`. Try replacing the `Data Source` keyword with `Server`, i.e.: `Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;initial Catalog={0};Integrated Security=True`.